# Upgrade to Xcode 12 SideMenue framework linked wrong

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode version is 11+, and the project works no problem.

Just upgraded to Xcode 12, but get this wired error:

> /MyProject.xcodeproj Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked
> framework 'SideMenu.framework' was built for iOS.

Get this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657913) and add `arm64` to `Excluded Architectures`, but no help.

Does anyone has the issue? thanks!

Comment: The error couldn't be more explicit. You're linking a iOS framework (arm64) for the simulator (x86_64). You need to either build for a device, or fix your project so you're linking against the simulator version of the framework for your simulator builds.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this is not the framework issue, it's Carthage issue, it's not works perfect along with Xcode 12.

This solution is from this [thread](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019):

The main idea is create a script exclude some arches then Carthage Build.

For Xcode 12  you can find the script here: https://gist.github.com/skymobilebuilds/61f4a95bd62a3db36b52719aeab7e0d5